# How can I run a odeint function with a for loop at the same time?

Tags: python, for-loop, odeint

I need to run 3 variables that vary through time inside a odeint function. I have 3 arrays with multiple elements and I want the odeint function to use the 1st element of the arrays for t=0, the 2nd element of the array for t=1...

I have tried placing the "for" inside "def" which results in it using only the first element of the arrays and if I place "def" inside "for" results in it only using the last element of the array
The arrays with multiple elements are: ur; utheta; uphi and they are calculated elsewhere in the code
here I can set up how many elements the arrays have and the time of simulation

The arrays with multiple elements are: ur; utheta; uphi and they are calculated elsewhere in the code
The number of elements is the same number as "time" given in the code

```
time=10

def c(zc,t):

    for cc in range(0, time):

        x1=zc[0]
        x2=zc[1]
        x3=zc[2]
        x4=zc[3]
        x5=zc[4]
        x6=zc[5]
        dx1dt=x2
        dx2dt= x1 * (x4 ** 2) * (sin(x5) ** 2) + x1 * (x6 ** 2) - (mu / (x1 ** 2)) + (3 / 2) * mu * J2 * (ae ** 2) * (3 * (((cos(x5)) ** 2) - 1) / (x1 ** 4)) + ur[cc]
        dx3dt=x4
        dx4dt= -((2*x2*x4) / x1) - 2 * x4 * x6 * cot(x5) + (utheta[cc] / (x1 * sin(x5)))
        dx5dt=x6
        dx6dt= -((2*x2*x6) / x1) + (x4 ** 2) * sin(x5) * cos(x5) + 3 * mu * J2 * ((ae ** 2) / (x1 ** 5)) * cos(x5) * sin(x5) + (uphi[cc] / x1)
        print(ur[cc])
        return [dx1dt, dx2dt, dx3dt, dx4dt, dx5dt, dx6dt]
z0 = [r, rdot, theta, thetadot, phi, phidot] #initial conditions provided elsewhere
t=np.linspace(0,time,time) 
zc=odeint(c,z0,t)
```

using "print(ur[cc])" I can see that "ur" is not varying through time like I want it to

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost: Providing a runnable example will help answerers of your question.

I'm assuming you're using [scipy's `odeint` function](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.odeint.html)

A few issues:

1. `time` is not an input to your function, but you use it in your function. While things may work for now, this is going to lead to unexpected behavior down the line.
2. You have a `return` statement *inside* your for-loop. So, you're only actually every running the case where `cc = 0`.
3. Rather than a for-loop, you should try vectorizing your code. [Here's an article](https://hackernoon.com/speeding-up-your-code-2-vectorizing-the-loops-with-numpy-e380e939bed3) which has some examples (NOTE: I skimmed it, but didn't read it in full).
4. The [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.odeint.html) indicate you should use [`scipy.integrate.solve_ivp`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.solve_ivp.html#scipy.integrate.solve_ivp) instead of `scipy.integrate.odeint`

Comment: moving the return back really helped, so now the output from "print(ur[cc])" are the correct values but instead of showing them 10 times (if time=10) it shows them over and over again. Any ideas on this? Thank you for the help thus far!

Comment: @PedroDente - I'm speculating here, but I would guess that `odeint` is going to call your function multiple times, thus your print statement will run 10x per function call. If my answer helped, please consider accepting it.

Comment: I do realize that but I still don't have a solution to my problem. the problem is solved once that print gives me only 10 values (if time = 10). Do you understand what I mean?

Comment: @PedroDente - I guess I'm a little confused. Since `odeint` will be calling your function multiple times, it's going to print out 10 values each time that function is called. So, a single call to `odeint` may result in, say, 5 calls to your function while it's solving. Then, you would expect 50 prints.

Comment: I tried to edit my comment, but SO wouldn't let me. `10 values each time that function` should read `10 values each time *your* function`

Comment: for time = 5, instead of printing the 5 correct values 5 times it's printing them 6320 times. What the ...

Comment: To help illustrate my point, comment our your print statement inside your for-loop. Add `print("my function was called!")` as the first thing your function does. You'll see that `odeint` is calling your function *many* times as it attempts to iteratively solve your problem.

Comment: Also, make sure you're being careful with item 1 in my answer. Your function isn't actually using the input `t` at all (at least in how it was written in your original question).

Comment: it is using t as I compared my simulated results with other softwares

Comment: In your original question, your function definition looks like so: `def c(zc,t):`. However, your for-loop looks like so: `for cc in range(0, time):`. Notice how you aren't using `t` in the for-loop. You *only* use it as an input to your function, but then don't actually use it in your function.

Comment: t=np.linspace(0,time,time)

Comment: "time" will be the same as t cause t ranges from 0 to "time" as well

Comment: What happens if you add a `print(t)` statement just inside your function definition?

Comment: it gives a ton of random values, 0,2.9680059131401165e-11
5.936011826280233e-11
2.968599514322745e-07
2.968599514322745e-07
5.936605427462862e-07
8.904611340602978e-07
3.858467047200415e-06
6.826472960340531e-06
9.794478873480647e-06
3.947453800488181e-05
6.915459713628298e-05
9.883465626768414e-05

Comment: @PedroDente - are those values being printed out like an array? Does it look like `array([0,2.9680059131401165e-11, ...])`?

Comment: @PedroDente - This illustrates my previous point. In your function, you do not use the input `t`, but rather use the variable `time` which is declared *outside* the function. It would appear that `odeint` is calling your function with a *scalar* value of `t`, so you should probably remove your loop entirely. I assume that as it attempts to solve at the points you gave it (`t=np.linspace(0,time,time); zc=odeint(c,z0,t)`, it's passing in different time values (that aren't in that `linspace`) to explore the space and come to a solution.